# The Ghost in Gold, a Cinderella-like story about Chiara, Lorenzo, Scintillio?

Tags: story-identification, cinderella

Over at TVTropes, a story "The Ghost in Gold" is mentioned in various contexts as literature, unfortunately without further identification:

[Big Eater](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/BigEater/Literature)

> In *The Ghost in Gold*, a Twice-Told Tale of Cinderella, Chiara spent years being her stepmother's half-starved slave, so good food is one of her biggest weaknesses. She inhales three courses at the masked ball without realizing it, and even when employed at the palace and getting regular meals, food is never too far from her thoughts.

[Oblivious To Love](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/ObliviousToLove/Literature)

> In the Cinderella reimagining, *The Ghost in Gold*, Chiara falls for Prince Lorenzo after he gives her a job at the palace so she can leave her stepmother's house, and she tells herself he will never be interested after he saw she's a pauper and not the princess she attended the ball as. When he proves to be very interested by seeking her out to spend time with, and giving her gifts, like a bouquet of her favourite flowers, an evening off to have dinner with her non-evil stepsisters, and new clothes for Christmas after she admitted to only having her maid uniform, Chiara thinks it's all coming from a place of pity. In the end, Lorenzo has to outright tell and assure her that, yes, he's in love with her for Chiara to finally understand.

[Canine Companion](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CanineCompanion)

> Chiara's sheep dog, Scintillio, in *The Ghost in Gold*. As a puppy, he is one of the last gifts from her father before he passes away, and a more prominent comfort during her situation than the family of mice typical to the source material. When Chiara becomes a maid at the palace, Prince Lorenzo invents a job for Scintillio in the stables so the girl and dog won't be separated.

There is a similar [question](https://www.librarything.com/topic/340118) at LibraryThing, without results.

Comment: Someone trying to publicise their fan-fic?  I can't find a single match anywhere, to the point that it seems bizarre.

Comment: I wonder if the story is not in English and *The Ghost in Gold* is a translation. The names sound Italian in which case the story might be *Il Fantasma in Oro* or something like that.

Comment: All those edits seem to have been made by the same user, most likely a self-published writer trying to get their book out there

Comment: @fez - I suspect that there's no source novel. More likely it's just someone inventing a load of nonsense to see if anyone references it

Comment: @Valorum I suspect the same, but it would make such a good story....